# Is there a Yahoo Mail "Notifier" for the Mac?

Tags: mac, yahoo-mail

There used to be a sanctioned application which was similar to Google's Gmail Notifier, but it seems to have disappeared into the ether.

I have also had no success finding a Dashboard widget for this purpose, even though it would be less convenient.

So, is there a "Yahoo Mail Notifier" app for the Mac?

Comment: Do you use Adium? It has an option to turn on Yahoo Mail Notifications.

Comment: Nope, don't use Adium.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo IM seem to do some of what you want. It displays the number of unread messages in your account.

Answer (score 1):

[Yahoo Widgets](http://widgets.yahoo.com/) has a widget that allows the checking of Yahoo mail and various others. It works nicely on Mac and Windows.

Comment: I'm looking for something Mac-native or a Dashboard widget - Yahoo Widgets (a.k.a Konfabulator) is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Mail Checker](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/email_messaging/mailchecker.html); it's a Dashboard widget that can check both Gmail and Yahoo accounts.

Comment: Yahoo breaks this because it doesn't send a User-Agent, so it assumes you're using an incompatible browser, and breaks the authentication flow. In short, this doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used it lately. The last time I used it, it was working ok.